# laravel eager loading relationship with where clause not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, relationship

I want to load that users that have a `company_id` = `28`. I put where clause but its not working, collection returning all records.

**MyController.php**

```
public function index($type, $company_id = '')
{
    $user = User::whereHas('roles', function ($query) use ($type) {
        $query->where('name', '=', $type);
    })->get();

    $users = $user->load(['userSetting' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('company_id', '28');
    }]);

    return response()->json($users);
}
```

**User.php**

```
public function userSetting()
{
   return $this->hasOne('App\UserSettings', 'user_id');
}
```

Comment: Do you have results in tinker when you do: `UserSettings::first();`

Comment: @HCK Yes, i have

Comment: Also, you have a `User 1-m UserSettings` so you just want to load the relationship for the only/unique user that is linked with the single record in `UserSettings` that comply with `user_id=28`?

Comment: What about: `$query->where('userSetting.company_id', '28');` as the eager loading condition? (I included the relationship name)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [filter](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-filter):

> The filter method filters the collection using the given callback, keeping only those items that pass a given truth test.

For example:

```php
$collection = collect([1, 2, 3, 4]);
$filtered = $collection->filter(function ($value, $key) {
    return $value > 2;
});
$filtered->all(); // [3, 4]
```

Within your controller:

```php
public function index($type, $company_id = '')
{
    $users = User::whereHas('roles', function ($query) use ($type) {
        $query->where('name', '=', $type);
    })->get();

    //If you want to load the relationship with the users:
    /*
    $users = User::whereHas('roles', function($query) use ($type) {
        $query->where('name', '=', $type)
    })
        ->with('userSettings')
        ->get()
    */

    $users = $users->filter($user){
        return $user->userSettings->company_id == 28;
    }

    return response()->json($users);
}
```

Hope it helps.